Maximize a function implicitly defined

Given the fucntion
$$y(b,x)\text=\frac{1}{b} e^{-b x} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(b-\frac{1}{b}\right) e^{-b^2 \frac{x^2}{2}}$$
with $b>1$ and $x>0$, I am looking for a formula (also an approximate one) expressing the maximum value of $x$ returning a given $y_1$, namely maximum $x$ for which
$$\frac{1}{b} e^{-b x} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(b-\frac{1}{b}\right) e^{-b^2 \frac{x^2}{2}}=y_1$$

As seen in the next plot, varying $b$ there is a maximum value of $x$ which gives say $y_1=0.5$.
y[b_, x_] := 1/b Exp[-b x] + Sqrt[2/Pi] (b - 1/b) Exp[-b^2 x^2/2]
Plot[{y[1.1, x], y[1.2, x], y[2, x]}, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]


This value can be found numerically with
NMaximize[{x, 
  1/b Exp[-b x] + Sqrt[2/Pi] (b - 1/b) Exp[-b^2 x^2/2] == 0.5, b >= 1,
   x > 0}, {x, b}]

{0.83263,{x->0.83263,b->1.39636}}
Considering that for $y(1,0)=1$, it is evident that for $y_1 \leq 1$, $a$ can have any value as long as it is larger than $1$, while $y_1 >1$ imposes the constraint $b >
 (2 \sqrt{2})^{-1}(\sqrt{\pi  y_1^2-4 \sqrt{2 \pi }+8}+\sqrt{\pi } y_1) $
Indeed
NMaximize[{x, 
  1/b Exp[-b x] + Sqrt[2/Pi] (b - 1/b) Exp[-b^2 x^2/2] == 1.5, b >= 1,
   x > 0}, {x, b}]

{0.315126,{x->0.315126,b->3.24899}}
y1 = 1.5;
ListPlot[Table[{b, NSolve[y[b, x] == y1 && x > 0, x][[1, 1, 2]]}, {b, 
   If[y1 <= 1, 1, 
    1/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) (Sqrt[\[Pi] y1^2 - 4 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] + 8] + 
        Sqrt[\[Pi]] y1) + 1^-7], 4, 0.02}], Frame -> True]

Thanks.


Some thoughts.
Let $Q := bx$. From
$$\frac{1}{b} e^{-Q} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(b-\frac{1}{b}\right) e^{- Q^2/2} = y_1,$$
we have (using $b > 1$)
$$b = \frac{y + \sqrt{y^2 + 4B^2 - 4AB}}{2B}$$
where $A := \mathrm{e}^{-Q}, B := \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-Q^2/2}$.
Thus, we have
$$x = \frac{Q}{b} = \frac{2QB}{y + \sqrt{y^2 + 4B^2 - 4AB}}.$$
We true to seek the maximum of $f(Q) := \frac{2QB}{y + \sqrt{y^2 + 4B^2 - 4AB}}$.
For example, $y_1 = 1/2$, solve $f'(Q) = 0$ to obtain
$Q = 1.162654038$ and $x_{\max} \approx 0.8326301748$.

River Li, amazing, thanks! Unfortunately we need however to resort to numerical computation, while I was focused on finding an explicit formula.

@umby Got it. Do you want to find an an explicit approximate solution? After some simulation, it seems $Q \approx 1$ if $y_1$ not small, e.g. when $y_1 = 10$, we have $Q = 1.000561069$. So we may use e.g. Taylor approximation at $Q = 1$.

It works well also if you just substitute $1$ for $Q$ in $f(Q)$, in this case you end up with $f$ being just a function of $y_1$. The Taylor expansion is fine, but then you need to solve for $Q$ and you get a very big formula, if this is what you mean.

@umby I don't know. Perhaps we can use all kinds of approximation, besides Taylor.

@ River Li, can you suggest an other approximation?

@umby For example, Pade approximation. But since $Q \approx 1$ when $y_1 \ge 1$, I think Taylor works well.
